# StructLayout Pack=1 doesn't work with bool?

Tags: c#, marshalling, native

Quiz: what does the following program print?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication2 {

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
    struct Struct1 {
        bool b;
        int i;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
    struct Struct2 {
        byte b;
        int i;
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Struct1)));
            Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Struct2)));
            Console.ReadKey();            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer:

```
8
5
```

This is very confusing to me. Both bool and byte have a size of 1 byte, and specifying `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]` should nullify any padding issues. Both structs should be 5 bytes. So I have two questions:

- Why does marshalling work this way?
- Any workaround? I have 1-byte booleans in native structs I need to import. I can use byte instead of course but it's "messy".

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By default, .NET type `bool` marshals to unmanaged type `BOOL`, which is `typedef`ed to `int`. If you want to marshal to and from 1-byte unmanaged booleans, indicate this to the marshaler with an attribute:

```
[StructLayout (LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
struct Struct3 {
    [MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.I1)]
    bool b;
    int i;
}

Console.WriteLine (Marshal.SizeOf (typeof (Struct3))) ; // prints 5
```

Comment: That's a glaring Microsoft-ism: bool is 1 byte in C and C++. It would have never occured to me that they would marshal to a Microsoft-specific typedef.

Comment: booleans are just integers in C (at least pre-C99). Only C++ has a native `bool` type. For interoperability using `int` as boolean is better, as it's more common.

Answer (score 3):

`bool` gets Marshalled to an `int32`, for interoperability reasons (C/C++ programs usually use `int` as booleans, and in winapi `BOOL` is `typedef`ed as an `int` as well), therefore it's converted to 4 bytes.